# How to populate all preg_match() with an array

Tags: php, regex

I have a string `"1 + 1 = 12, wrong"`
and an array `[1, 2, 3, 'correct']`
and the regex pattern `/(\d+) + (\d+) = (\d+), (\w+)/`

how to populate the matched result to the array value.

so the string will be `"1 + 2 = 3, correct"`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What other strings are likely to appear? `1 - 1 = 0, correct`? Might the spacing be different `1+1=3, wrong`?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution - maybe not the **best** - is to loop through what you matched with `preg_match()`, and to replace one by one.

```php
$str = '1 + 1 = 12, wrong';
$pattern = '/(\d+) \+ (\d+) = (\d+), (\w+)/';
$replacer = [1, 2, 3, 'correct'];
$result = $str;

if (preg_match($pattern, $result, $matches)) {
    // If there is enough matches, we can continue
    if (sizeof($matches) === (sizeof($replacer) + 1)) {
        // We begin at 1 because $matches[0] is the whole string.
        for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($matches); $i++) {
            // We use preg_replace because str_replace will replace all occurences of the match.
            $result = preg_replace('/' . $matches[$i] . '/', $replacer[$i - 1], $result, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I corrected your regex pattern.